# What is the difference between presupposition and supposition?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between presupposition and supposition?
Can they be used exchangeably?

> You  are  probably  familiar  with hypotheses in science, but throughout our lives we use hypotheses, suppositions
> we suspect to be true and for which we are seeking evidence.

> we will note that in our efforts to determine the truth, we inevitably begin with certain presuppositions, such as the ideas that the world exists and that every event has a cause.

> What is the presupposition of this seemingly unassailable assumption, "I think, therefore I am"?

Answer (score 2):

The prefix **pre-** is significant. A presupposition is something you already suppose to be true, maybe something that you have always taken for granted - 'that the world exists', as it says in one of your examples.

A supposition could be something you suppose to be true in the present circumstances, maybe just for the purposes of this scientific experiment.